# How to move back a folder in working directory and then move back up to another

Tags: r

```
wd = "//Parent//Child1"

setwd(wd)
```

I want to access a file in Parent//Child2, which means I need to go back to the Parent and then up to a different folder in the Parent folder. *'./Parent'* gets me from Child1 to the Parent, but I can't seem to figure out how to then move back up into Child2. Anyone know how to finish this line off?

Comment: two dots `../Child2`

Comment: I knew it would be something simple that I missed. Thank you @rawr!